# How do I kill the Cyclops robot knight?

Tags: battleblock-theater

Starting in the third world, there are these robots with one yellow/red eye who open their mouths to shoot homing rockets at you. They appear indestructible. Is there some way to take them out?

[image: chillin' on a robot]

Comment: I don't think is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Missile Bot's](http://battlewiki.battleblocktheater.com/Missile_Bot) can´t be killed but they can be temporarily deactivated** by melee attacks, some weapons, and it's own missile.

> The Missile Bot is a creature that can shoot Homing Missiles that kill
>   you. It can be stopped by 2 punches, and certain projectiles (such as
>   grenades).